# Windows 7 certificate problem while installing driver

Tags: windows, service, certificate, driver

I'm facing a problem while trying to install a signed driver on my Windows 7 computer.
In order to install the driver I'm using the command (CMD as Administrator):

```
sc create my_driver type= Kernel binPath= "c:\my_driver\driver.sys"
```

[Windows Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gePv.png)

[Driver signatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iShF.png)

The driver is working just fine in Windows 10

Comment: Could you provide details of **your problems** like for instance the error message you receive or the expected as well as the actual behavior?

Comment: I added an image with the error message I receive ('Windows Failaure')

Comment: Please add relevant error messages to the post directly, rather than  adding images.